# How can I use a enum in a datacontract WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I want to have an enum in a datacontract of a WCF webservice.

I am trying using

```
[DataContract]
class myclass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id {get; set;}

    [DataContract]
    public enum myenum
    { 
        [EnumMember]
        a,
        [EnumMember]
        b
    }
}
```

But I am not able to access enum at the wcf client. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To be included in the mex/wsdl, the enum needs to be **used** somewhere in the graph, for example there should be a property somewhere of type `myenum`. Types not *actively* used in the graph are omitted.

Note also that you don't actually need to annotate enums *at all* - they will work just fine. You only need attributes on enums if you want to customize how they act on the wire.

Comment: ... or if you want to publish certain enum values but not others

Answer (score 4):

As Marc said - use it. The datatype itself is not an issue until it is required iirc.

Part from that its not required to have Datacontract and EnumMember on it (special rules apply). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx for more information.